# Compiling Multiple C++ OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, compilation, header, g++

I'm writing a simple C++, opengl program and I'm having difficulty producing the executable from the object files. I can create object files of each .cpp without error using:

```
g++ -c filename.cpp  ---->   filename.o
```

Each .cpp creates an object, which leads me to assume that it is finding the opengl headers fine, but when I attempt to create the executable from the objects, it outputs:

```
g++ -o OUTPUT Main.o Time.o Map.o Vehicle.o

Main.o: In function `init()':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `glEnable'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `glShadeModel'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `glViewport'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x15c): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
```

I realize that the g++ is telling me that it can't find the OpenGL functions anywhere, which means it is not linking to glu.h, gl.h etc. But why do the objects files get created without similar error, but I can't make my executable? Wouldn't the object files suffer from the same linking error as the .exe? I've tried -I and g++ -o RUN Time.o Main.o Map.o Vehicle.o -L/usr/include/GL/ -lGL -lGLU, and I've also verified the path of the OpenGL directory.

The headers of each files are below:

libgl.h:

```
#ifndef LIBGL_H
#define LIBGL_H

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Time.h"
#include "Link.h"

#endif
```

Time.h:

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

extern float GLOBAL_TIME;

#endif
```

Map.h

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H
#include "libgl.h"
....
#endif
```

Vehicle.h:

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H
#include "libgl.h"
...
#endif
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "libgl.h"
#include "Map.h"
#include "Vehicle.h"
 ...
```

There is something that I'm missing regarding my headers/linking and compiling, if anybody has any suggestions I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 3):

You need to link with the OpenGL libraries: probably pass `-lgl` to the last g++ invocation.

If your system has `pkg-config` you can use `pkg-config --cflags --libs gl` to get all the right  flags.

For future reference, an "undefined reference" is a linker error, and it always means the same thing: you missed an object file or a library. It only shows up when linking, never when simply compiling (i.e. using `-c`)

Comment: or you forgot an include that has the inline version of a function

Comment: pkg-config yields: "-lGL". I tried "g++ -o OUTPUT Main.o Time.o Map.o Vehicle.o -lGL" --> undefined reference. I thought the whole point of having "#include <GL/glu.h>" was so the preprocessor could use the PATH to find the appropriate library/object, so wouldn't all the includes be redundant if I'm just going to find the libraries manually with "g++ .... -lGL"? If I take the "#include <GL/glu.h>" out, then I can't create object files with "g++ -c Main.cpp"--->undefined reference, so why would g++ be able to create object files with no complaints but not executable?

Comment: The `#include` only brings you the declarations. The actual code is compiled in a library somewhere, and that's what `-lGL` is for. To compile, it only needs declarations. To link it needs the actual compiled code so it can... well, link to it :) I don't know what the problem is then...